# Java/ contain/equal point class

Tags: java, point

I have a list of points, and I want to use the contain method. The problem is That I have the next List: `{(1,2), (2,3), (2,4)}`, but when I asked `list.contain((2,3))`, it gives me false.

I use `java.awt.Point`.

How can I change it to support this issue?

Comment: You mean `list.contains(new Point(2,3))`?

Comment: Show your actual code that shows this problem, instead of just a description. This should work if you implemented it correctly.

Comment: Is your `list` a collection with a custom comparator? This is the only reason that I can think of for which `list.contains(new Point(2,3))` would return `false`. In a normal collection this returns `true`. I just checked.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
list.contains(new Point(2,3))
```

Comment: If the list contains P1(1,2), P2(2,3), P3(3,4) and if we compare another object Pn2(2,3) to check if it belongs to the list then would it be true: P2.equals(Pn2)? Point doesn't implements Comparable.

Comment: It doesn't have to implement Comparable. It just has to overrite equals, which I think it does.

Comment: @CristianVrabie you are right. It does overrite the equals.`Point pt = (Point)obj;return (x == pt.x) && (y == pt.y);` From the source code.